# How to add Label text into rounded boxview

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add text over `BoxView` component through `AbsoluteLayout` in codebehind.
Something like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Here is my code, where I put `AbsoluteLayout` into `StackLayout` at the end:

```
 public TestPageBoxView()
    {
        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
        AbsoluteLayout al = new AbsoluteLayout();

        BoxView bv = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Green };
        Label l = new Label { Text = "Some text with \n breaks" };

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(l, new Rectangle(0, 0,1,1));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(l, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

        sl.Children.Add(bv);
        sl.Children.Add(al);
        Content = sl;
    }
```

So, my concern is that this `l` component is sticked to stacklayout and not for BoxView.

Maybe I should try with `RelativeLayout`?

Do you know some component on git? like XLabs?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually on my app, I used imageButton instead of button

Comment: @MikeDarwish is there any limitations, did u check for example how much big text can it hold? Tnx

Comment: standard image button has limitation. it doesnt mostly fit. there are some open bugs in mozilla and also if you want use text with image, it lays out the text on the right side of the image only. not possible to change as i remember last time. you should use image with tap gesture recognizer instead if you need an image button.

Answer (score 10):

You can try Frame instead of Absolute Layout like this

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#13CF13" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="40">
        <Label WidthRequest="40" Text="Backlog" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    </Frame>
```

Gives you this result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of How can I do this using a boxview and relative layout, but it is a sufficient alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but I just achieved this as following.

In XAML

```
<StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="2" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Caption}" Grid.Row="0"  FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Silver" FontSize="Large"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

And this is what it loos like in the app

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be achieved by Grid.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="buttonbg.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                <Label Text="I am Label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

</Grid>
```

Or in codeBehind Like below:

```
Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions = 
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Star }
                },
                ColumnDefinitions = 
                {
                     new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Absolute)
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
                }
            };

            grid.Children.Add(new Image
                {
                    Source = "buttonbg.png",
                }, 0, 1, 0, 3);

            grid.Children.Add(new Label
                {
                    Text = "I am Label",
                    TextColor = Color.Black
                }, 0, 1, 1, 1);

            this.Content = grid;
```

I have not taken alignment into consideration so you may have to look into that.

Comment: The question asks about BoxView.

Comment: @StuartAitken The can't be achieved using BoxView. BoxView Can't inherit other controls. so an alternate solution is provided above.

Comment: @ArunGupta It can be done using a combination of grid and boxview. See Salman solution above.